# Using tibco ems with spring boot3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, tibco-ems

We are using *Tibco EMS* for reading messages from a queue. This is done in a spring boot application. After migrating to `spring boot 3.x` we see errors that the javax.jms.Queue class can not be found. This is somehow clear because everything moved to Jakarta namespace. The specific version of tibco is `com.tibco.tibjms:8.5.1`

Questions.

- Is there a version of `com.tibco.tibjms` available that already uses Jakarta? (sorry I have some difficulties understanding the Tibco website to find it on my own)
- Is there a how-to that describes how I can solve the issue?

Comment: Not sure if there is however if you upgrade you will also need to upgrade the Tibco server to a version that supports Jakarta. You cannot just upgrade the client and have it work with an older implementation, that has to go in unison.

Comment: It looks like the tibco-server is already running on 10 something. We found a tibco library on our artifactory which has been moved to jakarta-namespace. But i do not see an "offical" tibco site which says what they provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIBCO EMS 10.2 supports Jakarta Messaging 3.0

See below extract from the release notes ..

This release adds support for the Jakarta Messaging 3.0 specification.
Jakarta EE, formerly Java EE, has renamed the javax.jms package into jakarta.jms with the Jakarta EE 9 release. The Jakarta Messaging 3.0 specification reflects the corresponding change of namespace. EMS implements both Jakarta Messaging 2.0 (javax.jms namespace) and 3.0 (jakarta.jms namespace) in the form of two sets of jar files – see the TIBCO Enterprise Message Service User Guide for details.

You must keep using the original set of jar files to run applications based on Jakarta Messaging 2.0 (also note that the JMS interface file has been renamed – see in the Changes in Functionality section) and switch to the new set to run applications based on Jakarta Messaging 3.0, primarily for use in the Jakarta EE 9+ world.