# Tibco ems service unavailable exception in jdk 17

Tags: spring, boot, java-17

Iam trying to connect tibco ems from spring boot 3.0, iam unable to connect tibco ems when using jdk17 getting service unavailable exception. When I try with simple main project for test jdk 1.8 able to connect tibco if I use jdk 17 not able to connect

Kindly suggest jms and tibco version need to use for spring boot 3 and jdk17 version

I tried simple main program to connect tibco ems with jdk 1.8 able to connect. If I connect with jdk 17 getting service unavailable exception

Comment: Tibco EMS, depending on the version, only supports JavaEE JMS. Whereas Spring Boot 3 requires JakartaEE JMS. Those aren't compatible. So if you are using an older version of Tibco EMS, you cannot upgrade without upgrading Tibco EMS as well.

Comment: Thank you Deinum, may I know what version of tibco ems supports spring boot 3?

Comment: It isn't about Spring Boot 3, it is about the version of JMS that Tibco EMS supports. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77301746/using-tibco-ems-with-spring-boot3 for what the minimal version is you will need.